# Grayscale, washed out effect for web page footer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

I am trying to duplicate [this](https://www.mozilla.org//media/img/home/voices/mosaic-background.565019b6e6bc.jpg) portrait mosaic -- inspiration courtesy of Mozilla's homepage -- for a company intranet footer. I'm a Photoshop neophyte (more adept with Illustrator) and don't know how to control for different source images and give them this same brightness? The process is more than simply changing the image mode and adjusting brightness/opacity. Is there some kind of adjustment layer? I can fiddle with precision but what would the general workflow be for something like this?

Thanks much, 
Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do that effect is to create two layers:

top layer = your photo
bottom layer = white

Then just adjust the opacity of the top photo to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be easier to set that opacity up with basic css code?
**img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}**
?
this way you don't have to fiddle with the image. However if you want a simple jpeg that won't have any interactive elements then there are few ways to achieve it with photoshop:
**solution 1.** once all the images are sized up you can drop them into a folder layer together and lower the opacity of the folder layer...this will distribute equal opacity to all images. 
**solution 2.** create your very top layer above all the portraits to be a single color ( white/light grey )  and lower its opacity as you see fit.